# Upgrade Windows Web Server 2008 toward "standard" edition?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have an instance of Windows Web Server 2008. Do you know if it is possible to upgrade it toward "Windows Standard Server 2008"? (I mean without a complete reinstall and considering that I have the license to do that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible if your server is x64:
https://serverfault.com/questions/10299/upgrading-windows-server-2008

and for vista is not a complete reinstall, what about [Windows Anytime Upgrade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Anytime_Upgrade)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be very surprised if it did.  Even upgrades in Vista between versions is pretty much a complete reinstall.